# After Defining new columns using values of a row in sql I want a new column that will be the summation of the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, case

I have the query of defining new columns using values of a row. Now I want another column that will be the summation of the new columns. I tried this,

```
SET @SQL = '
SELECT SC.Name AS BUYER, 
CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ANANTA'' THEN OM.OrderQty END AS Unit1_Qty,
CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ACWL'' THEN OM.OrderQty END AS Unit2_Qty,
CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''DNV'' THEN OM.OrderQty END AS Unit3_Qty,
CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ANANTA'' THEN OM.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit1_Value, 
CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ACWL'' THEN OM.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit2_Value, 
CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''DNV'' THEN OM.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit3_Value,

(Unit1_Qty + Unit2_Qty + Unit3_Qty) as TotalQty

FROM LineAllocation LA
INNER JOIN OrderMaster OM ON LA.OrderRef= OM.OrderRefID
INNER JOIN AmanOTS..FileRef FR ON FR.FileRefID = OM.FileRefID
INNER JOIN SystemManager..Contacts SC ON SC.Code=OM.BuyerCode
INNER JOIN SystemManager..ProductionProcessCostCenter PPC ON PPC.CostCenter= LA.Line
INNER JOIN OrderMasterCostBreakdown OCB ON OCB.OrderRefID= OM.OrderRefID
INNER JOIN SystemManager..ProductionProcess PP ON PP.ProcessID = PPC.ProcessId
where UseDate = '''+Cast(@MonthName As Varchar)+''' AND  ProcessName =''Sewing'' 
'
Exec(@sql)
```

But it does not work And showing error for using the alias name.

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Invalid column name 'Unit1_Qty'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Invalid column name 'Unit2_Qty'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Invalid column name 'Unit3_Qty'.

How can I do it?

Comment: I think you are not using CASE WHEN correctly. Why are you ending CASE at every condition. And why use CASE At every line.

Comment: you can't reuse an alias in the same FROM expression. Unit1_Qty, etc., are not known for TotalQty.

Comment: @ Paresh J There is no problem with the CASE WHEN.

Comment: @koriander I understand that but then how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing complicated about it. For any given row, you will only have one qty and one value according to the factory name.

```
Factory  Qty1 Qty2 Qty3 Val1 Val2 Val3
=======  ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ====
ANANTA   10   NULL NULL 12.5 NULL NULL
ACWL     NULL 20   NULL NULL 22.5 NULL
DNV      NULL NULL 30   NULL NULL 32.5
```

So just calculate the value indiscriminately at the end to get what you want:

```
...
CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''DNV'' THEN OM.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit3_Value,
OM.OrderQty * FR.Rate as TotalVal
...
```

You'll end up with something like this:

```
Factory  Qty1 Qty2 Qty3 Val1 Val2 Val3 TotalVal
=======  ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ========
ANANTA     10 NULL NULL 12.5 NULL NULL     12.5
ACWL     NULL   20 NULL NULL 22.5 NULL     22.5
DNV      NULL NULL   30 NULL NULL 32.5     32.5
```

**Addendum:** Just as a parting shot, if the three Valx fields may have values in any or all of them, then a summation field would look like this.

```
...
S1.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit1_Value,
S2.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit2_Value,
S3.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit3_Value,
( Nvl( S1.OrderQty, 0 )
+ Nvl( S2.OrderQty, 0 )
+ Nvl( S3.OrderQty, 0 )) * FR.Rate END AS TotalVal
```

Then the result would look like this:

```
...  Qty1 Qty2 Qty3 Val1 Val2 Val3 TotalVal
===  ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ==== ========
...    10   20   30 12.5 25.0 37.5    75.00
...    10 null   30 12.5 null 37.5    50.00
```

Comment: @ TommCatt, I can't do this because now I have null values but in future notnull values may come.

Comment: May come? Those null values aren't read in from the database. You specify the null values in your query. If they "may come" it will because you replaced the nulls with other values. So why don't you give us a complete description of what it is you are trying to do? Maybe give an example of just when and how there will be non-null values and what you want to see then.

Comment: I got the exact result from the another answar just using an extra-nullcheker. Becasue i Have only values in unit1_qty and unit1_value that means for only factoryname ANANTA.

Comment: The one other answer submitted, as written, can only show null in the generated field (value + null + null = null). I can only assume you know what you mean to say but just have trouble with English. The sample query you gave us takes one value from an input row and displays it in either the first, second or third field of the output row. All other fields must be null. So when you say that may change in the future, you are talking about a completely different query. I am indeed sorry I was not able to provide a useful answer to an unspecified future query.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry. I got it. Actually I never thought about this properly before because I was provided a report design format that contains data in each field. I am just sorry. And Thank you very much for your kind effort to make me understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

One method to use the column aliases in the expression is with a common table expression.  The example below also is a parameterized query instead of string concatenation.

```
SET @SQL = '
WITH
    allocations AS (
        SELECT SC.Name AS BUYER, 
            CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ANANTA'' THEN OM.OrderQty END AS Unit1_Qty,
            CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ACWL'' THEN OM.OrderQty END AS Unit2_Qty,
            CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''DNV'' THEN OM.OrderQty END AS Unit3_Qty,
            CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ANANTA'' THEN OM.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit1_Value, 
            CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''ACWL'' THEN OM.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit2_Value, 
            CASE WHEN PPC.FactoryName = ''DNV'' THEN OM.OrderQty * FR.Rate END AS Unit3_Value
        FROM LineAllocation LA
        INNER JOIN OrderMaster OM ON LA.OrderRef= OM.OrderRefID
        INNER JOIN AmanOTS..FileRef FR ON FR.FileRefID = OM.FileRefID
        INNER JOIN SystemManager..Contacts SC ON SC.Code=OM.BuyerCode
        INNER JOIN SystemManager..ProductionProcessCostCenter PPC ON PPC.CostCenter= LA.Line
        INNER JOIN OrderMasterCostBreakdown OCB ON OCB.OrderRefID= OM.OrderRefID
        INNER JOIN SystemManager..ProductionProcess PP ON PP.ProcessID = PPC.ProcessId
        where UseDate = @MonthName AND ProcessName =''Sewing'' 
        )
SELECT 
    BUYER, 
    Unit1_Qty,
    Unit2_Qty,
    Unit3_Qty,
    Unit1_Value, 
    Unit2_Value, 
    Unit3_Value,
    (Unit1_Qty + Unit2_Qty + Unit3_Qty) as TotalQty
FROM allocations;'

EXEC sp_executesql
    @sql
    ,N'@MonthName varchar(30)'
    ,@MonthName = @MonthName;
```